# Reverse geo coding return only one address when from Arrays of latitude , longitude

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I have an array of `CLLocationCoordinates2D` and set a for loop to call function `get_addres_from_geoCoder` but this function print only one address while CLLocationCoordinates2D array has 18 values(lat, long)

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  for a in My_rides_Pick_locatio
  {
     let loc =       CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:a.latitude,longitude: a.longitude)

     self.get_addres_from_geoCoder(loc:  loc)
  }
```

```swift
func get_addres_from_geoCoder(loc : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {


            let location: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: loc.latitude, longitude: loc.longitude)

            geo.reverseGeocodeLocation(location as CLLocation, preferredLocale: nil) { (clPlacemark: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
                guard let place = clPlacemark?.first else {
                    print("No placemark from Apple: \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }

                    print("----")
                    print(place.compactAddress!)

            }
    }
}
```

> Result

---

R A Bazaar Road, Rawalpindi, Pakistan

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apple restriction. See documentation.

> Discussion
>   This method submits the specified location data to the geocoding server asynchronously and returns. When the request completes, the geocoder executes the provided completion handler on the main thread.

After initiating a reverse-geocoding request, do not attempt to initiate another reverse- or forward-geocoding request. Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error object with the value CLError.Code.network to your completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is correct in the previous answer that you should not "spam" the Apple geocoding service with large numbers of requests as some may be dropped.  However in this case I'm not sure this is exactly what is happening as if it was each one that failed would be triggering your guard clause (as the completion handler is still called even for requests that are dropped according to the documentation) and you'd be getting the error message printed out 17 times.

It almost seems as if the goecoding service won't even accept a request if one is already active.  Some brief testing I've just done (because it's relevant for one of my projects, and I wanted to be sure I understood it) seems to confirm that as it will only return a response to the first coordinate submitted, and never returns an error for subsequent ones.

Therefore a better apporach to in your scenario would be to use an iterative approach, initiating the reverse geocoding of the remaining locations in the completion handler:

```
let geo = CLGeocoder()

func reverse(locs: [CLLocation], number: Int = 1){
   guard !locs.isEmpty else {
      print("All Done")
      return
   }
   geo.reverseGeocodeLocation(locs.first!){ placemarks, error in
      print("-------------- \(number) -------------")
      if let error = error {
         print("Error \(error)")
      } else if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
         print("place: \(placemark)")
      }
      reverse(locs: Array(locs.dropFirst()), number: number + 1)
   }
}
```

The number parameter and the prints statements are just in so you can easily see what's happening and would need to be removed from any final code base.

Just as a trivial demo of how to use it, there's an example below.  I've successfully processed an array of 20 locations in testing.

```
let c1 = CLLocation(latitude: 51.5074, longitude: 0.1278)
let c2 = CLLocation(latitude: 52.5074, longitude: -0.1278)
let c3 = CLLocation(latitude: 53.5074, longitude: -0.1378)
let c4 = CLLocation(latitude: 54.5074, longitude: -0.1578)
let c5 = CLLocation(latitude: 55.5074, longitude: -0.1778)

let c = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]

reverse(locs: c)
```